# Fix python sql select with variable

Tags: python, postgresql, variables, select

There is an error in how I am passing the variable in this sql select statement.

```
date_pass='2023-12-07'

print("Opening import list.....")

con= psycopg2.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="Zeitgeist_Storage",
    user="postgres",
    password="subsonic1")

sql = """   select * from permanent_full_scrape_data where date = %s;""" % (str(date_pass))

master_scrape_list_update_1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql,con)
```

the error is:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '   select * from permanent_full_scrape_data where date = 2023-12-07;': operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...lect * from permanent_full_scrape_data where date = 2023-12-...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Can write a sucessful select statement but have problems implementing the variable side.

Comment: The pattern  - as shown in the linked duplicate - is `cursor.execute(sql, (variable,))`; it's _not the same as string formatting_, so _not_ `sql % variable`.

Comment: Read the docs [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).